# A 1 meter radius ring spins around its axis at 10 revolutions per second. It is now dropped to the ground

Tags: homework-and-exercises, velocity, rotational-kinematics, rotation, angular-velocity

A 1-meter radius ring spins around its axis at 10 revolutions per second. It is now dropped to the ground, where it rolls steadily in a straight line. Assuming it does not lose any energy to friction, what is its final speed?

I have tried approaching this question via calculating the angular velocity of the ring in radians, which came out to be 20π since the radius is 1m (since 10 revolutions per second and each revolution is 2π radians). Now since linear velocity is equal to angular velocity multiplied by radius, it comes out to be 20π again, whose value is about 62m/s which is the wrong answer of course. I'm not sure what I should be doing here, and how to approach this question other than the above-mentioned way. Also, it asks the final velocity, which technically should be 0 but I do feel there's more to it. I would really like to know how to solve this question. And the correct approach to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there's no loss of energy during the impact (a *wrong* assumption, by the way) then apply conservation of energy:

$$T_{before}=T_{after}$$

'Before' the ring has only *rotational kinetic energy* $K_{R,1}$, calculated the usual way.

'After' the ring has both *rotational kinetic energy* $K_{R,2}$ for *angular velocity* $\omega_{after}$, **as well as** *translational kinetic energy*, for velocity $v_{after}$.

As you pointed out in your question, $\omega_{after}$ and $v_{after}$ are linked.

Using that relationship and the energy balance, calculate $\omega_{after}$ and $v_{after}$.

As this is a HW&E style question I'll leave it to you to fill in the blanks.

Comment: 1/2- Thank you so much for the approach, and I used it on my solution but I am getting stuck again. I'm sorry for asking stupid questions, but I am really weak at physics and I kinda need guidance all the time. So I used the energy balance relationship, and after solving the equation, I am getting (omega before/2)^2=(omega after)^2, considering the moment of inertia is MR^2 for the ring. Since omega before was 20 pi radians, solving it the omega after is coming to be around 44.3 radians/sec. (contd)

Comment: 2/2 (contd), and the velocity has to be the same (I am not sure about this, but since R=1m, I am assuming omega=velocity). But the answer provided says it is around 4.5 m/s, so where am I going wrong again?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't help you any further w/o breaking the site's rules. When carrying out this kind of algebra you need to be **very, very meticulous**, as one wrong iota will lead to catastr. error(s). So try again but very carefully and don't rush. Good luck.

Comment: I Totally understand, thank you so much anyway for guiding. I will keep trying!

Comment: You could upvote, as a means of saying 'thanks!' Up to you...

Comment: Oh no I actually did! But it says I need more rep points to upvote, so basically they didn't register my upvote.

Comment: Thanks for accepting.